# when user click the ok button of windows alert box the meassage is copied to users clip board using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have copied the div element to the alert box. Now when I pressed ok button is it possible the text is copied to the user's clipboard.

Here is the code for reference:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bn").click(function(event){
        $(alert($('#demo').text())
    });
});
```

Comment: If you would like to only copy the text depending on the clients response to the alert than maybe `confirm()` would be better as shown in this example [**JsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ogyjsby5/)

Answer (score 1):

`select();` to Select the text field and `document.execCommand("copy");`  to Copy the text inside the text field.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bn").click(function(event){
        var valueToCopy = $('#demo').text();
        $('#demo').append('<textarea id="temp"></textarea>');
        $("#temp").val(valueToCopy);
        $('#temp').select().text();
        document.execCommand("Copy");
        $("#temp").remove();
        $(alert(valueToCopy));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"> Hello java<br> Welcome to the world of programming<br> Error generated<br> Correction alert<br> </div> <div> <input type="button" value="clickToCopy" id="bn"> </div>
```

Comment: what if I have to select the div element rather than text field. Something like this:<div id="demo">
Hello java<br>
Welcome to the world of programming<br>
Error generated<br>
Correction alert<br>
</div>
<div>
<input type="button" value="clickToCopy" id="bn">
</div>

Comment: everything works fine except in alert.

Comment: then what should I use in place of alert?

Comment: @sakshiaggarwal check answer updated.

Comment: Thank u so much. It's really helpful :-)

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible.

In your html file include the below code.

```
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

In your js file include the below code.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>
```

For reference please visit the below link .

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_copy_clipboard

Hope this will resolve your issue .